# Whilst in the US on a 6 month trip on a B2 visa, can you leave the country and come back, say for a friend's wedding in another country?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

Whilst in the US on a 6 month trip on a B2 visa, can you leave the country and come back, say for a friend's wedding in another country?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE?  Is your visa Multiple Entry?  Is visa still valid for the time that you enter the country the 2nd time?

Comment: Thanks Karlson. Not sure if it is multiple entry. I am travelling from Australia and want to be in the US for 6 months, with a 2 week trip to South Africa in the middle for a wedding. I haven't had the visa interview yet because if it is not possible to do what i mentioned above, then there is no point in applying for it.

Comment: It is possible for multiple entry visa but not if you get a single entry visa.

Answer (score 2):

If you are leaving to Canada or Mexico, you can use automatic revalidation and re-enter on the same duration of stay you got the first time (and your visa doesn't even have to remain valid during this time). If you are leaving to somewhere else, then when you come back, it will be a new entry on B2, so your visa will need to be valid at that time, and you will get a new duration of stay.

Comment: I am coming from Australia and want to stay for 6 months. I wish to go to South Africa after 3 months for a friend's wedding. I haven't yet had my visa interview, just submitted an application for the B2 visa. No where does it say whether it is a multiple entry or not. Can I just go to South Africa for 2 weeks and then come back into the US without having to redo the paper work?

Comment: I hope you have a very good reason for getting a B2. The US has been fairly strict on issuing B2 visas to VWP nationals of late...  Then, ironically, once they deny your B2 application you can no longer use the VWP.

Comment: Can you provide a link or reference @user102008?

Comment: thanks @Doc. sounds like it is best to just go with the VWP, leave for the wedding in sth africa for ~3 weeks and then re-enter, thereby refreshing the 90 days with a new VWP. do you think there will be a problem if i buy a return ticket from the US to south africa? that is, i will enter on a return ticket from Aus to USA, then leave on a return ticket USA to SA and then finally depart the USA for AUS on that original return ticket?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Here's information about automatic revalidation, although it does not apply to the OP's case: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors

Comment: @RussellKaplan: But staying the full 3 months on VWP, going away for a brief trip, and then returning for another full 3 months on VWP, could be viewed as a "visa run".

Comment: @RussellKaplan Whether you get a multiple entry visa depends on your nationality; most people (and all who are nationals of VWP countries) automatically get multiple entry visas.